# How to create Dynamic Recyclerview with Predefined only 10 items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter, android-listadapter

On Screen load, i want to show 10 items in recyclerview with name with 1,2,...10 which defines the positions of items in recyclerview.

But when user is click on particular item on recyclerview, i want to replace that item with a user.

[image]

Comment: Then what the image attached relate to the problem?

Comment: I need to replace mic image with user profile image

Comment: Just create a recycler view with `GridLayoutManager` and `setOnItemClickListener()`  in the `recyclerAdapter` to change the image of the item clicked to user image

Comment: i am working on chat app, In one user changes item in their recyclerview, it should reflect same at other 9 user's recyclerview, i can't achieve with this